# is it possible to show the ChromeDriverManager download progress

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use ChromeDriverManager in project to do some automation test, I have tried to change the download url like this:

```
driver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager(
            url="https://repo.huaweicloud.com/chromedriver/",
            latest_release_url="https://repo.huaweicloud.com/chromedriver/LATEST_RELEASE"
        ).install())
```

now I fount the download process takes too long. is it possible to show the download progress or verbose log in Python?